# Zoom snaps to top screen on ScrollViewer with RichTextColumns

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I'm facing a strange problem with `ScrollViewer` component in my Windows Store App. It has inside a `RichTextColumns` which displays text in columns that can be scrolled horizontally.

I enabled zooming with the attribute `ZoomMode="Enabled"`, but when I release my fingers when zooming (to stop the action), the scroll goes smoothly to the top (therefore, if I want to zoom the bottom of a column of text, the app automatically moves to the top and I can't see the desired text).

At first, I thought it was a problem with snapping points, but setting `VerticalSnapPointsType="None"` and `ZoomSnapPointsType="None"` in the `ScrollViewer` attributes don't fix the issue.

This is the code (it's the same you can get creating a new project in Visual Studio using the default template called "Grid application" [*Aplicación de cuadrícula* in spanish]):

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" Style="{StaticResource HorizontalScrollViewerStyle}" Grid.Row="1" ZoomMode="Enabled" VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" VerticalSnapPointsType="None" ZoomSnapPointsType="None" VerticalSnapPointsAlignment="Far" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
      <common:RichTextColumns x:Name="richTextColumns" Margin="117,0,117,47">
          <RichTextBlock x:Name="richTextBlock" Width="560" Style="{StaticResource ItemRichTextStyle}" IsTextSelectionEnabled="False">
                <Paragraph>
                     <Run FontSize="26.667" FontWeight="Light" Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                     <LineBreak/>
                     <LineBreak/>
                     <Run FontWeight="Normal" Text="{Binding Subtitle}"/>
                </Paragraph>
                <Paragraph LineStackingStrategy="MaxHeight">
                     <InlineUIContainer>
                          <Image x:Name="image" MaxHeight="480" Margin="0,20,0,10" Stretch="Uniform" Source="{Binding Image}" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}"/>
                     </InlineUIContainer>
                </Paragraph>
                <Paragraph>
                     <Run FontWeight="SemiLight" Text="{Binding Content}"/>
                </Paragraph>
          </RichTextBlock>

          <common:RichTextColumns.ColumnTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                      <RichTextBlockOverflow Width="560" Margin="80,0,0,0">
                            <RichTextBlockOverflow.RenderTransform>
                                  <TranslateTransform X="-1" Y="4"/>
                            </RichTextBlockOverflow.RenderTransform>
                      </RichTextBlockOverflow>
               </DataTemplate>
          </common:RichTextColumns.ColumnTemplate>
    </common:RichTextColumns>

    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenLandscape"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="Filled"/>

            <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenPortrait">
                 <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="richTextColumns" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                           <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="97,0,87,57"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="MaxHeight">
                          <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="400"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Snapped">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="richTextColumns" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="17,0,17,57"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="scrollViewer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                          <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource VerticalScrollViewerStyle}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="richTextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width">
                         <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="280"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="MaxHeight">
                         <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="160"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
</ScrollViewer>
```

However, when I set the attribute `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` to `Enabled` (`Auto`, `Hidden`, etc), zoom works as expected, but the text is shown in a single column (with vertical overflow). The text must be shown in multiple columns.

I'm missing something? How can I make it work with columns?

Thank you in advance.